# How to group by multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to group by my dataframe by different columns based on UserId,Date,category (frequency of use per day ) ,max duration per category ,and the part of the day when it is most used and finally store the result in a .csv file.

```
name     duration  UserId  category    part_of_day    Date 
Settings   3.436    1    System tool      evening   2020-09-10 
Calendar   2.167    1    Calendar         night     2020-09-11 
Calendar   5.705    1    Calendar         night     2020-09-11 
Messages   7.907    1   Phone_and_SMS     night     2020-09-11 
Instagram   50.285   9   Social            night    2020-09-28  
Drive       30.260   9  Productivity       night    2020-09-28   

df.groupby(["UserId", "Date","category"])["category"].count()
```

my code result is :

```
 UserId      Date        category               
1       2020-09-10    System tool                  1
       2020-09-11     Calendar                     8
                     Clock                         2
                    Communication                  86
                  Health & Fitness                 5
```

But i want this result

```
 UserId      Date        category             count(category)  max-duration 
1       2020-09-10  System tool                  1            3

        2020-09-11  Calendar                     2            5

2       2020-09-28    Social                     1            50
                      Productivity               1            30
```

How can I do that? I can not find the wanted result for any solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to group by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156174/how-to-group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: Please stop to post the same question over and over again, you can reference answers instead of posting same question with some tags and just altering the question name by adding python.

Comment: Just go back to your question and accept one that solves the problem or helps to solve and refrain for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `agg`:

```
df.groupby(["UserId", "Date","category"]).agg({'category':'count',
                                               'Date': np.ptp})
```

or replace `np.ptp` with `lambda x: x.max() - x.min()`.

Comment: this error was raise :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Turn your dates to datetime type with pd.to_datetime

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name    ': {0: 'Settings', 1: 'Calendar', 2: 'Calendar', 3: 'Messages', 4: 'Instagram', 5: 'Drive'}, '  duration': {0: 3.4360000000000004, 1: 2.167, 2: 5.705, 3: 7.907, 4: 50.285, 5: 30.26}, ' UserId': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 9, 5: 9}, '  category': {0: '       System tool', 1: '       Calendar', 2: '       Calendar', 3: '       Phone_and_SMS', 4: '       Social', 5: '       Productivity'}, '     part_of_day': {0: '  evening', 1: '     night  ', 2: '     night  ', 3: 'night  ', 4: '       night  ', 5: ' night  '}, ' Date': {0: '     2020-09-10', 1: '     2020-09-11', 2: '     2020-09-11', 3: '     2020-09-11', 4: '     2020-09-28', 5: '     2020-09-28'}})
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

df:

```
        name  duration  UserId              category     part_of_day             Date
0   Settings     3.436       1           System tool         evening       2020-09-10
1   Calendar     2.167       1              Calendar         night         2020-09-11
2   Calendar     5.705       1              Calendar         night         2020-09-11
3   Messages     7.907       1         Phone_and_SMS         night         2020-09-11
4  Instagram    50.285       9                Social         night         2020-09-28
5      Drive    30.260       9          Productivity         night         2020-09-28
```

```
grouping = df.groupby(["UserId", "Date","category"]).agg({"category": 'count', 'duration':max}).rename(columns={"duration" : "max-duration"})
```

grouping:

```
                                             category  max-duration
UserId Date            category                                    
1           2020-09-10        System tool           1         3.436
            2020-09-11        Calendar              2         5.705
                              Phone_and_SMS         1         7.907
9           2020-09-28        Productivity          1        30.260
                              Social                1        50.285
```

Answer (score 0):

You take advantage of [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) , [pandas.DataFrame.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename) in following format to generate your desired output in one line:

---

#### code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Settings','Calendar','Calendar', 'Messages', 'Instagram', 'Drive'],
                   'duration': [3.436, 2.167, 5.7050, 7.907, 50.285, 30.260],
                   'UserId': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'category' : ['System_tool', 'Calendar', 'Calendar', 'Phone_and_SMS', 'Social', 'Productivity'],
                   'part_of_day' : ['evening', 'night','night','night','night','night' ],
                   'Date' : ['2020-09-10', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-28', '2020-09-28'] })

df.groupby(['UserId', 'Date', 'category']).aggregate( count_cat = ('category', 'count'), max_duration = ('duration', 'max'))
```

#### out:

[image: output from one line]